# systemd forking vs simple?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd

I am writing my first `systemd` unit file.

For `Type`, there are a few choices: `forking`, `simple`, etc.  I have read the [Redhat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files#tabl-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Sec_Options) on this topic (Table 9.9) , but still am not sure when I should use which option.

Any guidelines?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

When you start the service manually from the command line (without using the `nohup`prefix command or the `&` suffix to run it in the background, or in other words, just run the command you would put on the `ExecStart=` line of the `.service` file), what happens?

**a)** If the service starts and keeps running, and the prompt does not return until you press Control-C or stop the service in some other way: then `Type = simple` (or `Type = exec` if your version of `systemd` has it) is the right choice.

The practical difference between `Type = simple` and `Type = exec` is mostly in error detection: `Type = simple` will proceed with other jobs as soon as systemd has `fork()`ed a new process for it, and so it may allow dependent things to proceed even if invoking the actual `Exec=` command fails. On the other hand, `Type = exec` will check the `Exec=` command actually gets invoked successfully and reports a failure if not.

So, if your `systemd` is new enough to support the `Type = exec`, you might prefer using it over `Type = simple` for better error checking. But if you need the boot to proceed as quickly as possible, and rapid detection of the start-up failure of your service is not essential, and/or you wish to be compatible with older versions of `systemd`, you might still use `Type = simple`.

**b)** If the prompt returns but the service keeps running in the background (i.e. the service daemonizes itself on its own), then `Type = forking` is the right choice.

**c)** If the service does its job and returns to the prompt without leaving anything running (i.e. the service just adjusts some kernel settings, sends a command to something else or does something similar), then `Type = oneshot` is probably the right choice. In this case, `ExecStart` of the service might be the command to "set" something, and `ExecStop` would be the corresponding command to "unset" it. This type usually benefits of `RemainAfterExit=true`, so systemd will keep track of the "state" of this service according to whether the thing was most recently "set" or "unset".

The other `Type` values are special cases. For example, if the service utilizes a D-Bus connection, then `Type = dbus` might be the best choice. It makes `systemd` aware of the fact, and then systemd will track this service (and anything that depends on it) by the presence of this service on the D-Bus.

To use `Type = notify`, the process must be able to connect to Unix socket specified in environment variable `$NOTIFY_SOCKET` and to report its status by writing messages to that socket whenever necessary. Also, the service file should specify the `NotifyAccess` option to grant access to the notification socket as appropriate.

There is a command-line utility `systemd-notify` and a C library function `sd_notify(3)` you may use to send these messages, but if neither of those is suitable to your requirements, you can just implement your own message sender. The messages required are very simple, and look like shell variable assignments: for example, to notify that the service has successfully completed startup and is ready to serve any incoming requests, the service should send the string equivalent to the output of `printf "READY=1\n"` to the socket. See `man 3 sd_notify` for more details on the recognized messages.

Note: many service applications designed to be portable to many Unix-style systems may behave as b) by default, but can be made to work like a) by adding an option (usually described as "don't fork", "keep running in foreground", "don't daemonize" or similar). In that case, if the option has no other side effects, then adding the option and using the a)-type behavior would be preferable for `systemd`.

Comment: Suppose I start `apache`,which type should be used?

Comment: Well, how would you start it manually? By running `apachectl start` as root, perhaps? Try doing it, and see what happens. Then pick a), b) or c) from my answer. I'd bet that the prompt returns and Apache remains running, so b) would be the answer.

Comment: I really like the explanations you gave in your answer. Would you mind adding another plain English explanation for the case of `Type=notify`?

Comment: Description of `Type=notify` added.

Comment: @telcoM Add one for exec too

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer Back when I initially wrote this, `Type=exec` did not exist. Added.